# Helm kube-prometheus-stack stuck in pending-install

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kube-prometheus-stack, kube-state-metrics

Problem: For some reason, helm release of `kube-prometheus-stack` is stuck in `Pending-install` status. What is the correct to install a helm release for this using `helm cli`?

**Details:**

Due to Docker registry `k8s.gcr.io` getting frozen, I had to update the Docker image registry to `registry.k8s.io` for `kube-state-metrics` by updating the `values.yaml` as follows:

```yaml
kube-state-metrics:
  prometheusScrape: true
  image:
    repository: registry.k8s.io/kube-state-metrics/kube-state-metrics
    tag: v1.9.8
    pullPolicy: Always
  namespaceOverride: ""
  rbac:
    create: true
  podSecurityPolicy:
    enabled: true
```

After that, when I tried update the helm release for `kube-prometheus-stack` using same version of `14.9.0`, it failed with status `Failed` for helm release. Upon retrying, it deleted the previous helm release and created a new one. All the components by the new one created successfully but the helm release got stuck in the `Pending-install` status.

I waited for almost 30 minutes but no success. I also tried deleting helm release, rollbacking helm release, deleting helm release secret but got no success.

What could be the issue? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** After some investigation, I found that there was a job named `kube-prometheus-stack-admission-patch` which was failing with `BackoffLimitExceeded` error. It was some kind of an initializing job. Deleting the job (not pod) fixed the issue and the helm release changed its status to `Deployed`.

**Error Log in `kube-prometheus-stack-admission-patch` job:**

```
W0331 10:58:03.079451       1 client_config.go:608] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
{"level":"info","msg":"patching webhook configurations 'kube-prometheus-stack-admission' mutating=true, validating=true, failurePolicy=Fail","source":"k8s/k8s.go:39","time":"2023-03-31T10:58:03Z"}
{"err":"the server could not find the requested resource","level":"fatal","msg":"failed getting validating webhook","source":"k8s/k8s.go:48","time":"2023-03-31T10:58:03Z"}
```

Comment: This is probably you are using older version of `kube-webhook-certgen` or `kube-prometheus-stack`. `kube-webhook-certgen` < 1.3.0 is not compatible with k8s clusters > 1.22 . If you are using cluster version 1.23 or grater, you may need to upgrade kube-prometheus-stack version >1.40 or use `kube-webhook-certgen` v1.3.0 or grater

Comment: hi @pgollangi, I have the similar issue after using the latest version of kube-prometheus-stack (helm version: 48.3.1) and I have checked the version of kube-webhook-certgen is v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6, which I think is v1.3.0 or greater. 
I've got the following error: `failed to do request: Head "https://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen/manifests/v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6": dial tcp: lookup us-west1-docker.pkg.dev on 10.0.0.2:53: no such host `
Do you have any ideas?